# loop through table find first td text which have css csstablelisttdselected

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 <table id="tableWorkList" class="csstablelist" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="csstablelisttdselected" style="display: none;">
    246
    </td>
    <td class="csstablelisttdselected" style="display: none;">
    2
    </td>
    <td class="csstablelisttdselected">
    n
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

**i have to loop through table and find first cell text which have css class name csstablelisttdselected**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

```
$('table td.csstablelisttdselected:first').text();
```

Answer (score 1):

Then you don't need a loop

```
var tdtext = $('#tableWorkList td.csstablelisttdselected:eq(0)').text();
```

The query gets all `td`'s with `class csstablelisttdselected` under the table id'ed `tableWorkList`.

The `eq(0)` gets the first element in the collection gathered by the query.

Answer (score 1):

You can use in jQuery as

```
$('#tableWorkList').find('.csstablelisttdselected:eq(0)').html();
```